# Extract csv rows that match with pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've huge csv file and I need to fetch only rows that match with below pattern 
For example

```
A
Abc://a/b/c/1/2/3
Abc://a/b/c/d/1/2/3
Abc://a/b/c
Abc://a/b/c/e/f/g
```

And pattern is
`Abc://a/b/c/*/*/*`

Please share your ideas.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.loc` indexing functionality like so:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'Abc://a/b/c/1/2/3') &
       df['A'] == 'Abc://a/b/c/e/f/g')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it return other rows - Abc://a/b/c/d/1/2/3 where I just need to fetch only below rows Abc://a/b/c/1/2/3 and Abc://a/b/c/d/e/f/g

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df['PATR'].str.contains('Abc://a/b/c/(?!$)', na=False)
df1 = df[mask]
df2 = df[~mask]
```

Try this,probably this will work